# Android SQLite unable to upgrade database

Tags: android

The onUpgrade method is called every time the phone restarts and I can see that the oldVersion parameter in onUpgrade never gets called. I have tried uninstalling the application but with no success. The weird thing is that the oldVersion is always 6. Or could there be any other reason why my database is gone every time the phone restarts?

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    /**
     * jdbc Constructor.
     * 
     * @param context
     */

    Context mContext;
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      mContext = context;

    }

    /**
     * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)
     */
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      LogToSD.write((getClass().toString() + " " + LogToSD.getMethodName(2)), "Enter");
      try {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_1);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_2);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_3);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_4);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_5);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unable to query database", e);
      }
    }

    /**
     * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,
     *      int, int)
     */
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      LogToSD.write((getClass().toString() + " " + LogToSD.getMethodName(2)), "Enter");
      String version = "oldVersion " + Integer.toString(oldVersion) + " newVersion "
        + Integer.toString(newVersion);
      LogToSD.write((getClass().toString() + " " + LogToSD.getMethodName(2)), version);


      if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        try {
          //DROP OLD
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_1);
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_2);
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_3);
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_4);
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_5);
          //CREATE NEW
          onCreate(db);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.toString();
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

SOLVED
So it looked like they were doing nothing in the constructor, but moved everything into a initialize method.

```
Class Store {
 public Store() {
    db = null;
    table = new HashMap<String, String>();
  }

 public void initialize(Context context) throws SQLException {
    if (db == null) {
      dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
      db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
  }
}
```

They did this because they were using a factory that would only create a single instance of the Store if it did not exist, but they could not get the context from the factory. So what they did was call the initialize method from one of the activities. So by moving those things into the constructor and removing the initialize method everything worked. I noticed that the initialize method was called from more than one place. If I understand correctly, it doesn't matter how many times getWritableDatabase is called because the database is a singleton correct?

So my question is, even though this might not be the best practice, why did this not work?

Class Store {
 public Store(Context context) {
      dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
      db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.toString();
    }
```

To this:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Unable to upgrade database", e);
    }
```

The stack trace printed should explain your problem. If it doesn't, post it here and we'll take a look. :-)

Comment: it isn't getting an exception though?

Comment: How do you know? Did you make the change I suggested and run the app again?

Comment: Alright, I think i have the problem fixed. It had to do with the class that was calling the dbhelper. I will share the issue later. Thanks

Comment: Could it be that a database is linked to a databasehelper and by creating another database helper, the database gets lost?

Comment: The database is tied to `DATABASE_NAME` and not to any particular instance of a `SQLiteOpenHelper`. I'm confused about your solution, however. Are you saying that that `onUpgrade` was never being called?

Comment: I am a little confused myself. The problem that I had before was that onUpgrade would get called, but the oldVersion would never get changed. For some reason oldVersion was always 6. If i built it with DB Version as 7, onUpgrade would get called and oldVersion would show as 6. If i then changed DB Version to 8, onupgrade would get called again and oldVersion would be 6. It was always 6 regardless of what I did. I would uninstall the application and it was always 6.